# Change javacup parser inheritance

Tags: java, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

Currently I have the default javacup parser extending from java_cup.runtime.lr_parser, is there any way to have it also implement a interface I have created?

i.e:

```
public class Parser extends java_cup.runtime.lr_parser implements MyInterface {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out though, I modified the source files of javacup to add an extra argument option and I also did it using ant, in the build xml to replace certain tokens with others

Answer (score -1):

Classes can extend a class and implement an interface. It's all over the JDK e.g.

```
    public class TreeMap<K,V>
            extends AbstractMap<K,V>
            implements NavigableMap<K,V>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable { ...}
```

Comment: I was talking about having java_cup generated classes extend certain files